# How to limit the result of an operation to a specific range?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let's say I have $a = 1 / b$, and the highest possible value for $b$ is $1$ and the lowest is $0.1$. Because of this, the result range of the operation is from $1$ to $10$. I want to turn that from $1$ to $10$ range into a different arbitrary range, like turning it into range from $0.1$ to $2$ or something else.

*Background:*

In a wind brass instrument, there is an inverse relationship between the intensity of the blow and the attack time of the sound (attack time is the time it takes the sound to reach its peak amplitude, in seconds). The higher the intensity of the blow, the shorter the attack time is. I'm trying to emulate this using sound synthesis.

The implementation I started with is $attack time = 1 / amplitude - 0.99$ . The amplitude values range from 0 to 1. This means that the attack range is from 0.01 to 9.01 seconds. The problem is that the actual attack time range of a brass instrument is different, 9 seconds is way too much time.

Let's say the actual attack time range of a brass instrument is [0.1, 2]. What I'm looking for is an implementation that works for the input ranges [0.1, 1] and that outputs in the range [0.1, 2] (or any other arbitrary output range). Maybe by converting the output value to its equivalent in another range, maybe using other formula, maybe extending the original formula.

Comment: Its not really clear what you are asking!  Why do you want this? can you give ,ore background?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I'm sorry, my math really suck and I don't even know how to correctly formulate the question, and at the same time I didn't want to make the question too localized. I've added some background to the question. Thanks for your time and help.